# Clojure and compile time checking of spec

Tags: clojure, macros, clojure.spec

I'm playing with function specs and I'm wondering if one could use it to emulate compile-type checking?
Macros are evaluated at compile time, so if I could do something like this:

```
(:require [clojure.spec.alpha :as s]
          [clojure.spec.test.alpha :as st])

(s/fdef divide
        :args (s/cat :x integer? :y integer?)
        :ret number?)

(defn divide [x y] (/ x y))

(st/instrument `divide)

(defmacro typed-divide [arg1 arg2]
  (eval `(divide ~arg1 ~arg2)))

;; this should fail to compile?
(defn typed-divide-by-foo [arg]
  (typed-divide arg :foo))
```

Comment: FYI `(typed-divide arg 2)` would through an exception too, since the symbol `arg` is passed in at compile time. You can only use `typed-divide` to divide things whose value is known at compile time, which is pretty much limited to literals. `(typed-divide 2 :foo)` should give you a spec error though.

Comment: `(eval 'x)` is the same as `x`, so the body of `typed-divide` can be simplified to `(divide ~arg1 ~arg2)`.

Comment: It could be: `(defmacro typed-divide [arg1 arg2] (divide arg1 arg2))`. But then indeed only throws when both arguments are known at compile time: `(defn typed-divide-by-foo [] (typed-divide 6 :foo))`. It's a purely academic investigation though I have no problem with dynamic nature of clojure :)

Comment: Whoops, you're right, no `~`. I assume you get a spec failure exception for `(typed-divide 6 :foo)` and an "Unable to resolve symbol" exception for `(typed-divide arg :foo)`?

Comment: Look at: https://github.com/arohner/spectrum It will catch exactly the error you have at compile time. Its still early alpha, but a better long term solution then what you are proposing.

Answer (score -1):

Although there might be some trick with macro system, your'd better to just write unit tests for that. Compile-time errors are quite vague and prevent REPL from being started. Instead, tests handle exceptions as well and collect nice reports when something goes wrong.

It's also not a good idea to instrument a function in production because it really slows down its performance. Instrument them only in tests. See example below:

```
(ns project.tests
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [project.code :refer [divide]]))

;; here, in test namespace, you instrument a function 
;; you'd like to test
(st/instrument `divide)

;; and then add a test
(deftest test-divide
  (is (= (divide 6 2) 3)))
```

now, run the tests:

```
lein test
```